# When does the UIViewController get deleted in ARC

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, automatic-ref-counting, dealloc

I am  Working on a ARC based project. I got two ViewControllers. In the First ViewController I have a button, on pressing that button I am pushing the new ViewController.

I am doing it as follows:

```
SecondViewController *second=[[SecondViewController alloc]initWithStrVal:self.strVal];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
```

My problem is when I push the SecondViewController,and then create an object of the `FirstView Controller` in `SecondViewController` the dealloc method in `FirstViewController` gets called.

Where as the dealloc method doesn't get called if I only do the  push and don't create  an instance of `FirstViewController` in `SecondViewController`. As far as I have heard when I push a View Controller, `dealloc` shouldn't  be called in the normal scenario, because the previous ViewController shoudn't deleted in the normal Scenario in ARC based project

**EDIT:**

The First ViewController is set in the app delegate as follows :

```
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil]; 
self.navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController]; 
self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
```

Comment: It's deleted because you probably have no more reference to your first  controller.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler the navigation controller should hold a reference on it though!

Comment: Yea Exactly .. Navigation controller Should hold a reference . Thats the normal behaviour

Comment: How are you setting up the first view controller? Can you show that code? Is it possible you have two instances of the first one?

Comment: Just now I observed that , the dealloc method of the First ViewController gets called only when I try to create an instance of First ViewController in the Second ViewController

Comment: Otherwise , if do push , without creating the instance of the First in the second , the dealloc is not getting called . I feel this is strange

Comment: @jrturton : the First ViewController is set in the app delegate as follows :self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];                                self.navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;

Comment: Then what's your problem? If you create another one instance of your FirstController and release it, the dealloc method of this one will be called, as expected. You should compare the address pointer of your FirstController into your navigationController and the one who is actually deallocating. I bet they are not the same